# How to properly measure elapsed time in background in Swift

Tags: swift

I have this two functions that measure the elapsed time when the phone is locked or the app is in background:

```
func saveTimeInBackground(){
    startMeasureTime = Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
}

func timeOnAppActivated(){
    stopMeasureTime = Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
    elapsedTime = stopMeasureTime - startMeasureTime
    seconds = seconds - elapsedTime + 2
    if seconds > 0 {
        timerLbl.text = "time: \(seconds)"
    } else {
        seconds = 0
        timerLbl.text = "time: \(seconds)"
    }
}
```

and then in the viewDidLoad() i have observers that are trigger the functions when the app becomes active/inactive:

```
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(saveTimeInBackground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(timeOnAppActivated), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
```

The problem is that when the app becomes active there are 2 seconds (approximately) of difference so i've added 2 seconds and it seems to work fine, but only if the elapsed time is > 15 seconds.
If i lock the phone and immediately unlock it the there are like 5 or more seconds that are missing. For example, if there are 50 seconds left, when i lock and immediately unlock it there are like 42 seconds left.

Can anyone please explain, what i am doing wrong?

**Edit**: The logic of the app is this:

It starts a match between 2 players with 60 seconds for a game. The problem is that when one of the players locks the phone the app stop to measure the time. This way if the player1 has 10 seconds left to make a move, the player2 still has 50 seconds left. I'm looking for a reliable way to calculate the time even if the player locks the phone or put the app in background.

**Edit 2**:  I think i figured out what the problem is: I think the issue has to do with the fact that the “seconds” are Int, and the Date not and when it gets converted it’s rounded up. I didn't tested it, but when i ahve the solution i'll post the answer. Thanks all for your time!

Comment: shouldn't it just be `seconds = elapsedTime + 2`?

Comment: seconds = 60, elapsed time = 10, seconds (on active) 60 - 10 (the elapsed time), not just 60 = 10

Comment: anyway, it can be seconds -= elapsedTime or seconds -=  stopMeasureTime - startMeasureTime but i found it better this way, for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, like I mention in the edit 2 of the question:
The first issue was because "seconds" is a Int and then it almost always gains or lose when converting it from Double.

But the main problem was that i had to invalidate the timer when the app enter in background and i didn't.

So now with invalidating the timer when the app gets the notification that will enter background and then starting it when it enter foreground everything works fine.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but I am doing something of similar sorts, and thought you could help me. I am invalidating a timer before the app goes to background and then making a new instance of timer when it the app returns to foreground. The timer does invalidate but when I open then app again, the new timer doesn't work. More details here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762833/creating-a-new-instance-of-timer-when-app-enters-foreground

Answer (score 2):

You're relying on exact timing of notifications that aren't guaranteed to have any exact timing. There's no guarantee about when, exactly, either of those notifications will arrive, and there's nothing you can do about that. Even your two-second fix is, as you say, approximate. It'll probably be different on different models of iPhone or even at different times on the same iPhone, depending how busy iOS is when you check.

What's more, when you go into the background, you can't be certain that you'll stay there. Once in the background, iOS might decide to terminate your app at any time.

I'm not sure what the goal is here but I think you'll need to reconsider what you want to do and see if there's some other approach. Your current two-second hack will, at best, spawn a bunch of other hacks (like the 15 second threshold you mention) without ever being especially accurate. And then it'll probably all break in the next iOS update when some iOS change causes the timing to change.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but just had to unmark it because there are timer apps, that can do this thing, measure the exact time they were on background. once again, thanks for your time!

Comment: For example, can you name an app that tells you exactly how long it took from the app going into the background until it comes to the foreground? I have never heard of one.

Comment: sure, this one https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/seconds-interval-timer-for-hiit-tabata-training/id475816966?mt=8 uses something like this to calculate the elapsed time when the phone was locked

Comment: The description of that app makes no mention of telling you how long the screen was locked for, only of measuring how long it has been since a starting time. It's not the same thing that you asked about.

Comment: it's possible that i wasn't clear enough. i'm going to edit the question.

Comment: just edited the question. sorry if i wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Date object to track game time.

```
func gameStart() {
    gameStartDate = Date()
}

func timeOnAppActivated() {
    let secondsLeft = 60 - abs(gameStartDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow ?? 0)
    if secondsLeft > 0 {
        timerLbl.text = "time: \(secondsLeft)"
    } else {
        timerLbl.text = "time: 0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To test this properly call those methods on button click. It may be coz of delay in releasing some resources in background.

Comment: Hi Jitendra, thanks for your time, but that does not answer my question. I think you should post it like comment instead.

Comment: Okay thanks to let me know where should i comment for suggestions