# Creating a new instance of Timer when app enters foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, elapsedtime

I am creating an app where a timer is set by the user. When the app goes to the background, the `timer.invalidate()`. Now I want the timer to start again when the app comes back to the foreground. I am creating another instance of timer to do it when the app sends notification that app is in the foreground. However, it's not firing the function.

In `Viewdidload()` I am creating a timer:

```
 timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.current.add(self.timer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
```

And then I have notifications that check if the app is in background or in foreground:

When it enters background I am invalidating the `timer`.

```
  @objc func applicationDidEnterBackground() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let quitTime = Date()
    defaults.set(quitTime, forKey: "quitTimeKey") //Storing the time of quit in UserDefaults
    timer?.invalidate()

}
```

When the app gets back out, I first check if the `timer` is isValid or not, and then create a new timer. But this timer doesn't seem to work.

```
@objc func appEntersForeground() {
    calculateTimeLeft()
    if let timer = timer {
        if (!timer.isValid)
        {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
```

}

Some help here will be appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code tried so far?

Comment: store the starting time as `TimeInterval` in userdefaults. and start the timer with balance time when app become active.

Comment: I just added the code. Please check. I am storing the time when the app went to the background in userdefaults. Then extracting that time and comparing it to the current time and then subtracting that time from the original.It's just that timer doesn't run again when the app comes back to the foreground.

Comment: @Kamran Just added the code in the post. Please check. I wasn't invalidating the timer before the app went to the background and that caused some issue with the accuracy of the remaining time. But now after invalidating the first timer, I am unable to start another timer once the app returns to the foreground

Comment: assign  return of Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) to your variable-> timer and check

Comment: do `timer = Timer.scheduledTimer` in `appEntersForeground`

Comment: @Kamran tried that! Not working

Comment: @vivekDas Not working!

Comment: check it is going inside the if condition or not ? also from which delegate method you are calling appEntersForeground method ?

Comment: `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterBackground),
                                               name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification,
                                               object: nil)` Using NotificationCenter

Comment: @vivekDas Yep, just tested. It's not going inside the if statement

Comment: don't check any condition in the appEntersForeground method and do : -> timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

Comment: doing that essentially runs two timers at the same time. Since I am running the same peice of code in viewDidLoad as well as in appEntersForeground. I need to run one of two timers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `timer` property as `weak`:

```
weak var timer: Timer?
```

Then it will be set to `nil` when the `timer` is invalidated.  Then just check if `timer` is `nil` before creating a new one:

```
@objc func appEntersForeground() {
    calculateTimeLeft()
    if timer == nil {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```